# Complex analysis-Mean theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

is the Mean theorem valid for complex analysis
i mean if f is analytic in a convex region, can we alawys find a point c
on the line segement between two points of this region(a,b)
so that:

f(a)-f(b)=f'(c)*(a-b)
??

Comment: [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Generalization_in_complex_analysis)

Answer (score 1):

No. Examples :(1)  $f(x)=e^x-1.$ Then $f(0)=f(2\pi i)=0$ but $f'(x)=e^x$ is never $0.$ (2) $f(x)=x^3-1.$ None of the line segments joining 2 of the 3 zeroes of $f$ contains a zero of $f'.$ (3) If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n\geq 3$ and $p$ has $n$ distinct zeroes, no 3 of which are colinear, then  there exists a set  $S$ of at least $n$ segments joining pairs of roots, such that no two members of $S$  intersect except at their endpoints. Then $p'$ is not $0$ at endpoints of these segments, and $p'$ cannot vanish on every member of $S$ because $2\leq \deg (p')<n.$

Comment: there is a point i did not undestand,
if i took f(z)=(z-1)*(z-2)*(z-3)
as you say  s has three elements while it has only two.
am i right??

Comment: sorry. I left something out .I am going to fix it.